# How to set animation sequentially for each to image after it loaded in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried @load and :class (posts from axios):

```
<div v-for="post in posts">
    <img :src="post.img" :class="{'someAnimation' : isImgLoaded}" @load="onImgLoad">
</div>


data: () => ({
    isImgLoaded: false
}),

methods: {
    onImgLoad() {
        this.isImgLoaded = true
    }
}
```

It sets animation for images of the entire list simultaneously, but it should be for each post with an image separately after loading.

Comment: then use multiple flags?

Comment: or add a property to `post` like `post.loaded`?